# VBScript - Wait for a process to finish, before going to another line

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I use a visual basic script to change ip addresses in windows seven. is there anyway to set it in visual basic.net that it has to wait for the vbscript to finish before carrying on to the nest line?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly.

Comment: @Hans, could you make an answer of this so that the question gets answered ?